# Pandas merge only new data in SQLite database

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I'm a absolute newbie in SQL and just started working with it. I have a SQLite database with stock prices and their dates.

With an API, I then read the newest stock prices and want to update my database and add only the new prices with the new dates. But I want to keep the old ones in the database. I get them from the API as a pandas dataframe. My API is returning duplicates and i don't want to have duplicates in my database.

I am using Python 3.6 and sqlite3 as an engine.

Here is one example set of the data from the data:

```
                     1. open  2. high  3. low  4. close  5. volume
date                                                              
2020-04-09 16:00:00  571.925   573.01  571.73    573.01   117287.0
2020-04-09 15:59:00  572.000   572.00  571.45    572.00    56954.0
2020-04-09 15:58:00  571.450   572.00  571.28    571.90    63987.0
2020-04-09 15:57:00  571.560   572.00  571.26    571.42    50978.0
2020-04-09 15:56:00  570.990   571.61  570.58    571.49    30975.0
```

I tired a proposed solution from https://www.ryanbaumann.com/blog/2016/4/30/python-pandas-tosql-only-insert-new-rows. But I get an error:

```
KeyError: Index(['date'], dtype='object')
```

The code is used is:

```
df_new=clean_df_db_dups(data, tablename, conn, ['date'])
print('New:',df_new.head())
```

Any help would be nice. This is just my second Stackoverflow post so if i am doing something nor right just tell me ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pd.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) which has a parameter called `if_exists` which expects the behaviour if the table already exists in the database, you can use `if_exists="append"` and if you already have the table it will just append the pandas data frame.

Comment: Yes basically this would work but i have duplicates in my API and have to filter them out.

Comment: You can use pandas drop_duplicates to drop the duplicates in the dataframe if that's what you mean. But if you want unique values in the dataframe I suggest reading this:https://www.ryanbaumann.com/blog/2016/4/30/python-pandas-tosql-only-insert-new-rows

Comment: Okay thank but is there a possible solution directly with the sqlite3 module?

Comment: I personally don't know any, sorry!

Comment: Okay, no problem. I tried the solution but I get an error (in the question edited)